# Getting a PHP variable in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

So I have this:

```
<?php
 echo '
  <script>
$(function(){
   $("a#yeah").click(function(){
           $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php?action=yeah&id='.$id.'",
        success: function(html){
         $("a#yeah").html("your cool")
                   }
     })
   })


})</script>';

?>
```

basically I am using the PHP variable $id which can be find in the document, how could I get this same variable but without echoing the jQuery(so I could keep my editor syntax highlight in the JavaScript part)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

never echo any client side code - just type it as is.
PHP especially good in this http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

```
  <script>
$(function(){
   $("a#yeah").click(function(){
           $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php?action=yeah&id=<?php echo $id?>",
        success: function(html){
         $("a#yeah").html("your cool")
                   }
     })
   })


})</script>
```

Comment: So this actually work, never thought it worked as it is so strangely rendered in the editor, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can add the php inline like:

```
<script> var yourVariable = '<?php echo $phpVar; ?>'; </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just echo around the variable, as that appears to be the only piece requiring processing:

```
      ...stuff...
      url: "ajax.php?action=yeah&id=<?=$id?>",
      ...more stuff...
```

If your server doesn't have `short_open_tag` enabled, then `<?php echo $id; ?>`